# Why does Views PHP give me NULL for $row->path?

Tags: 7, views, path-aliases

I have a views block to display only the titles of some few nodes. Titles linked to the single node. I want to have a CSS class `.active` added to the title's links when the linked path matches the actual called path. As mentioned in the comments below, I didn't got that class by default.

So I added a `Global: PHP` field right after I added and excluded a `Content: Path` field to access `$row->path` in the `Global: PHP`'s output code field. But `$row->path` seems to be empty. `dpm($row)` gives me a `path: NULL`. `Content: Path` displayed gives me the right paths. But where's the path gone in the PHP field??? When was the moment it got nulled?

I still managed to do what I want with the `nid`. Though without the beautiful alias paths I'ld like to have.

Comment: if these titles are linked, then there is nothing to do. The active link should already have `active` class.

Comment: Well... It doesn't.

Comment: Why are you using PHP rather than Views' own handling? This sounds like something Views will do out-of-the-box, though your question doesn't really explain the motivation.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - Are you just having a feeling or do you try to suggest a profound answer?

Comment: I was suggesting that you need to explain more about what your PHP code is trying to do. Generally, if you want to generate a link to content, it's easy to get Views to do that so I was wondering why you had resorted to PHP.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - You got the part with the CSS class, did you? If path == linked path, add class xyz to linked field. If you found another way, please let me know :)

Comment: Please explain why you are using PHP to achieve this. If you use the built-in Views link to content, you should get the active class automatically.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong - Well, I didn't got the class...

Comment: If the current page URL matches that of an A tag on your page, and if that tag was generated using the l() function (which it will if it was generated using Views), it should have the active class. If it doesn't, that is a different issue to the one you have raised here.

Answer (score 2):

Found a workaround for using the alias path in Views PHP: [[SOLVED] Views PHP $row->path showing Null](https://drupal.org/node/1992100)

```
drupal_lookup_path('alias', 'node/' . $data->nid)
```

Question still unanswered. Will report issue.

Comment: For me it's null the same

Comment: @PonzioPilato - Excuse me, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I tried to use the function you suggested, but no way, still the final value is null :(

Comment: @PonzioPilato – Well, then consider asking a new question.